# Javascript File load other Javascript files With no window/document

Tags: javascript, jquery, tfs, jsdom

I'm working with javascript file that has no window or document.
I have package.json file that calls another Javascript file task.js
package.json:

```
   {
  "name": "mytask",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "mytask TFS Build",
  "main": "scripts/mytask.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "install": "npm install"
  },
  "repository": {},
  "author": "OST",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "https-proxy-agent": "1.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.3.1",
    "jsdom": "13.0.0",
    "load-json-file": "^2.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "object.values": "^1.0.4",
    "request": "2.81.0",
    "vso-node-api": "^5.1.2",
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "5.141.0",
    "vsts-task-lib": "1.1.0"
  }
```

}

TFS call javascript file exist in package.json "main" option.
package.json call mytask.js via "main" option and this javascript file will run as a task in TFS and print things to console.

Basically my issue that there's no HTML page or document so I cannot load javascript file through  or document.addElement...

I need to load javascript file (VSS.SDK.js from vss-web-extension-sdk)  to mytask.js.
I'm new in javascript so I don't really know what I'm doing wrong.
After long searching, I found "jsdom" which creates a global document. But still didn't know how to load VSS.SDK.js script.

mytask.js:

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { window } = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>`);

var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);

 // Option 1
    jQuery.loadScript = function (url, callback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'script',
            success: callback,
            fail: callback,
            async: false
        });
    }

    jQuery.loadScript('vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.js', function(){console.log("loaded!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")});


    // Option 2
    jQuery.getScript('vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.js').done(function(){console.log("loaded!!!!!!!!!!!!!")}).fail(function(){console.log("failed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")});


    // Option 3
    jQuery.getScript('vss-web-extension-sdk/lib/VSS.SDK.js', function() {
        VSS.init({explicitNotifyLoaded: true, usePlatformScripts: true, usePlatformStyles: false});

        var serverContext = VSS.getWebContext();
    });
```

I tried these three options but it didn't work! nothing was printed.

I use VSS.SDK to load webContext.
any ideas?

Comment: Hmm ... What do you actually have? json file is not JavaScript file, and a json file doesn't definitely call anything.

Comment: it's not really that json file calls javascript file. But I work with TFS which use package.json file and call the javascript specified in "main" tag.